# Сумма и сортировка элементов

Tags: c

Вообщем, уже думал было все работает, но оказалось не так. Нужно подкоректирвовать код

Код:

```
int suma(int **math, int m, int n)
{
    int x1, x2, summa = 0;
    for (x1 = 0; x1 < m - 1; x1++) {
        for (x2 = 0; x2 < n - 1; x2++) {
            if ((x1 % 2 == 0) && (x2 % 2 == 0)) {
                summa = summa + math[x1][x2];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Summa: %d", summa);
}
```

Сумма элементов, оба индекса которых четные. Но почему-то неверно считает. думал по идее верно, так как смотрится индекс и если без остатка делится на два, то его считаем. Например, [2][4] элемент матрицы берем в сумму, а элемент [1][2] не берем. В чем ошибка?
n-1 взял, так как Си, нумерация с нуля. Думаю так.

Код:

```
int sortirovka(int **math, int m, int n)
{
    int x1, x2, k, s = 0;
    printf("n");
    printf("tNew Matrix:nn");
    for (x1 = 0; x1 < m; x1++) {
        for (k = n - 1; k > 0; k--) {
            for (x2 = 0; x2 < k; x2++) {
                if (math[x1][x2] > math[x1][x2 + 1]) {
                    s = math[x1][x2];
                    math[x1][x2] = math[x1][x2 + 1];
                    math[x1][x2 + 1] = s;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (x1 = 0; x1 < m; x1++) {
        for (x2 = 0; x2 < n; x2++) {
            printf(" %d", math[x1][x2]);
        }
        printf("n");
    }
}
```

Упорядочивание строк по неубыванию их наибольших элементов. Не так работает, просто сортируются в *строках* элементы, а не сами строки. Поэтому нужно подкорректировать, чтобы сортировались сами строки.

**Пример**

> `1 2 7 
> 4 3 5
> 2 0 9`

Должно выдать

> `4 3 5 //наибольший элемент 5
> 1 2 7 //наибольший элемент 7
> 2 0 9 //наибольший элемент 9`

А сейчас выдает

> `1 2 7 
> 3 4 5
> 0 2 9`

Помогите подкорректировать код.

Comment: Ответ так и не получен.Я и задал вопрос чтобы подкоректировали код,а не писали что он плохой или хороший,я только учусь,так что меня можно понять

Comment: @wapdimon72u, Вы границы циклов при вычислении суммы поправили ? И так и не получилось ?

В сортировке переставляйте строки целиком. Напишите функцию swapstr(int **a, int N, int M, int str1, str2)

Comment: Да верно это и было,я это иправил,все работает как надо,а скажите что такое notfin = 1; за что оно отвечает?

и за что отвечает w,что такое?

Comment: Про notfin -- в ответе, признак того, что массив ещё не отсортирован. w -- просто вспомогательная переменная для обмена значений, потому как питоновские `a, b = b, a` в C/C++ не предусмотрены. Точно так же и w1.

Comment: Вроде добавил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь

```
   for (x1 = 0; x1 < m - 1; x1++) {
       for (x2 = 0; x2 < n - 1; x2++) {
```

Почему m-1 и n-1, а не m и n? И сортировка очень уж странная, какой-то мичуринский гибрид пузырька и (не знаю как называется) самой дубовой.

Добавление:

```
int suma(int **math, int m, int n)
{
    int x1, x2, summa = 0;
    for (x1 = 0; x1 < m; x1 += 2)
        for (x2 = 0; x2 < n; x2 += 2)
            summa = summa + math[x1][x2];
    printf("Summa: %d", summa);
}
```

Сумма. Только считать элементы math[0][0] (первый элемент первой строки), math[2][2] чётными или нечётными -- это еще вопрос.

```
int sortirovka(int **math, int m, int n)
{
    int x1, x2, k, s = 0;
    printf("n");
    printf("tNew Matrix:nn");
    for (x1 = 0; x1 < m; x1++)
        for (k = 0; k < n-1; k++) 
            for (x2 = k+1; x2 < n; x2++)
                if (math[x1][k] > math[x1][x2]) {
                    s = math[x1][x2];
                    math[x1][x2] = math[x1][k];
                    math[x1][k] = s;
                }
    for (x1 = 0; x1 < m; x1++)
        for (x2 = 0; x2 < n; x2++) {
            printf(" %d", math[x1][x2]);
        }
        printf("\n");
}
```

Сортировка самая дубовая (название, как уже сказал, не помню). Берётся первый элемент строки и сравнивается с остальными. Если больше -- взаимно обмениваются. Далее так же со вторым, третьим и т.д. до [n-2]. Количество сравнений не зависит от начальной упорядоченности массива.

Проверять эти правки -- не проверял.

Дополнено:

```
int suma(int **math, int m, int n)
{
    int x1, x2, summa = 0;
    for (x1 = 1; x1 < m; x1 += 2)
        for (x2 = 1; x2 < n; x2 += 2)
            summa = summa + math[x1][x2];
    printf("Summa: %d", summa);
}

int sortirovka(int **math, int m, int n)
{
    int x1, x2, k, s = 0, *maxelems, notfin;
    printf("n");
    // поиск максимальных элементов в строках
    maxelems = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*m); // исправлено
    for(x1=0; x1 < m; x1++) {
        maxelems[x1] = math[x1][0];
        for(x2=1; x2 < n; x2++)
            if(maxelems[x1]  < math[x1][x2]) maxelems[x1] = math[x1][x2];
    }
    printf("tNew Matrix:nn");
    notfin = 1; // признак того, что сортировка не закончена
    while(notfin) {
        notfin = 0; // сброс. Если перемещения строк не будет, то останется нулём
        for (x1 = 0; x1 < m-1; x1++)
            if(maxelems[x1] > maxelems[x1+1]) {
                int *w = math[x1];        // вспомогательная переменная для обмена указателей на строки
                int w1 = maxelems[x1];    // вспомогательная переменная для обмена максимальных значений в строках. Должны перемещаться синхронно
                // math[x1] <-> math[x1+1] и maxelems[x1] <-> maxelems[x1+1]
                math[x1] = math[x1+1];
                math[x1+1] = w;
                maxelems[x1] = maxelems[x1+1];
                maxelems[x1+1] = w1;
                notfin = 1;               // обмен был. будет следующий просмотр массива
            }
    }
    for (x1 = 0; x1 < m; x1++)
        for (x2 = 0; x2 < n; x2++) {
            printf(" %d", math[x1][x2]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    free(maxelems);                  // освобождение памяти массива максимальных значений по строкам. 
}
```

Была ошибка в типе в строке

```
    maxelems = malloc(sizeof(int*)*m);
```

д.б.

```
    maxelems = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*m);
```

Комментировать больше не могу, лимит исчерпан. notfin -- признак, что сортировка ещё не закончена. При сортировке пузырьком сравниваются соседние значения и, при необходимости, меняются местами. После первого прохода массив ещё не отсортирован. Осуществляем второй и т.д. Признаком того, что массив отсортирован, является отсутствие перемещения значений при просмотре. Где-то так.

Comment: Ответ (кто его сотворил?) дополнен

Comment: Сумма.Элементы всей матрицы считать,в синумерация идет с нуля поэтому
четным считать [1][1] [1][3] и так далее,и про сортировку,этот код делает тоже самое что и мой,тоесть сортирует В строках числа,а НЕ сами строки

Comment: Что касается чётных/нечётных -- надо просто изменить начальные значения x1=1 и x2=1. Что касается сортировки, то сейчас д.б. сортировка строк по неубыванию максимальных эл. методом пузырька. Исправления в ответе

Comment: maxelems = malloc(sizeof(int*)*m); на эту строку что ругается,не хочет компилится

Comment: Матом ругается или приличными словами? Во-первых, там есть ошибка в типе. Во-вторых, если у Вас c++ (хотя в этом случае malloc лучше не пользоваться -- некошерно, лучше new/delete) и отсутствует `#include <stdlib.h>` то будет ругань на необъявленную (нет прототипа) функцию malloc (для c++ лучше `maxelems = new int[m];` и `delete [] maxelems;` вместо free).

Comment: @wapdimon72u, подозреваю, что у Вас c++ и ругается:

    error: invalid conversion from `void*' to `int*'

Добавьте явное приведение типа (int \*) : 

    maxelems = (int \*)malloc(sizeof(int \*) \* m);

Comment: @avp Да в ответе добавил. Тем более, что д.б. `sizeof(int)`. Ну и нефиг в "це с крестами" с malloc'ами баловаться -- new есть. Там и байтики считать не надо, и тип не надо приводить.

Comment: что такое notfin = 1; и за что оно отвечает?

и за что отвечает w,что такое?

Comment: А можете просто закоментировать подробно код?чисто чтобы разобратсься,где сортировка строк,просто отредактируйте пост,чуть ли не каждую строку,там ведь не долго для вас